# Are there in Russian any inanimate masculine nouns ending on -я?

Tags: грамматика, существительные

Are there any Russian inanimate masculine nouns ending in -я?

I can think of many feminine ones (торговля, трескотня, болтовня, мастерская, спальня, келья, etc.), but are there any masculine ones?

Comment: just to confirm: are you asking about declinable nouns? *па*, *квенья* and similar are masculine inanimate, but undeclinable.

Comment: I am asking about masculine inanimate nouns regardless of whether they decline or not. Looks like an answer to my question. Please re-write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a number of indeclinable masculine loanwords ending in *-а, -я*:  *квенья*, *фула*, *гёдза* etc. which accepted the gender of their respective generic terms: *язык* ("language"), *пельмень* ("dumpling")

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, some names of some cities would fit the bill:

> В древности **Антакья**, именовавшийся как Антиохия-на-Оронте, был важным
>   политическим и культурным центром, столицей империи Селевкидов. Сейчас
>   он является центром турецкого района Хатай
>
> **Вея** (араб. وع‎‎) — небольшой город на востоке Джибути, в регионе Арта.
>   Расположен на дороге N1, которая соединяет город со столицей страны.

Comment: Please note that Антакья and Вея aren't Russian ones.

Comment: @brilliant: city names in *-а*, *-я* are treated as feminine in Russian if they decline at all. The masculine in the quotes agrees with implied *город*.

Comment: Evidently the masculine gender here refers to noun город rather than the city name.

Comment: @Quassnoi - "**city names in -а, -я are treated as feminine in Russian if they decline at all. The masculine in the quotes agrees with implied город**" - So, I am puzzled, does that meant that such phrases like "Можга всегда был городом Удмуртии", "Мянття всегда был финским городом", "Ханья не всегда был городом Греции", "Чувашский Шумерля,  вначале был посёлком, а потом стал городом" are all grammatically wrong?

Comment: @brilliant: not sure whether *Мянття* and *Ханья* decline, but the rest are definitely wrong.

Comment: @Paul - "**Please note that Антакья and Вея aren't Russian ones**" - Well, I kind of know that :) And so what? "London", for example, is not Russian either, and in English it is neutral. However, when in it turns into Russian "Лондон", then it becomes masculine and gets all kinds of forms, which it doesn't have in English.

Comment: @Quassnoi - What about such phrases like "Можга всегда был в Удмуртии", "Шумерля уже тогда был на картах Чувашии"?

Comment: those too, unless you prepend them with *город*.

Comment: @brilliant , Вы можете сказать **"Можга красивое."** The present-day grammar is a context-free grammar. The future grammar will become increasingly more advanced and more intelligence (read: more mathematical), and would have to take into account the context. [I quote](http://www.mozhga-gov.ru/city/history.php): *Село Можга было возведено в ранг города.*

Comment: @Avtokod - "**I quote: Село Можга было возведено в ранг города**" - But in that case the name _"Можга"_ is preceded by the word  _"Село"_, which means that _"было возведено"_ agrees with _"Село"_ rather than with _"Можга"_.

Comment: @brilliant , I think I have an answer, it's [here](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/what-gender-do-place-names-take-if-they-do-not-end-in-letters-that-mean-that-a-g/9201#9201)

Answer (score 0):

No.

only animate: суд**и**я, месс**и**я, дядя,

ровня. this is common: он ровня, она ровня. also animate

In addition: http://lit.lib.ru/m/martinowich_g_a/2rod_s.shtml

Comment: I thought both of these are animate.  They both refer to a human being.

Comment: Ну уж если одушевленные в пример, тогда самые распространенные: `папуля, дедуля, сынуля` :)

Comment: ровня is not common. It is feminine: он - моя ровня, not он - мой ровня. Similar to пара.

Comment: @Anixx [wiktionary - ровня](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F)

Comment: @Anixx хотя, конечно, "он — моя ровня" убеждает))